# How to play Mid Lane as Akali agaist Morgana?

Tags: league-of-legends

I really like to play Akali and always try to go for the mid lane, because many people underrate Akali there and get easily killed by me. I can handle mid lane agaist most champions except Morgana, Annie and Mordekaiser, but **especially** Morgana gives me trouble.

If I attack her with  Level 6 or higher (with shadow dance and 3 marks) she stun me and her burst of damage takes me down while I can't do enough damage to kill her.

If I don't attack her she will push the lane very hard and I lose the tower after a while and if my teammates play bad at their lanes, I can't support them either than they can support me.

So how could I handle such a bad situation?

Comment: You state Morgana is the problem, then give an Annie example.  How does Morgana shut you down?

Answer (score 10):

Simple answer - *You shouldn't mid as Akali vs a Morgana.*

1. She will be a better harasser

   - Her AoE and snare will wear you down faster than your Q will on her
   - Your smoke bomb is nearly useless vs her AoE and ultimate
2. She farms better

   - Your farming skills mean you have to get in auto attack range, her AoE will slowly wear you down
   - She has spell vamp as passive, so her laning presence is very strong
3. She is too strong vs your skills

   - Your harassing depends on auto attacking after marking. She can spell shield when you are in range, then AoE > Snare.
   - AoE and ult > your smoke bomb

If you have no choice then I would:

- Use Flash to get out of sticky situations with her snare and ult (Smoke bomb + Flash is just absolutely amazing for escaping)
- Use your smoke bomb to farm more safely
- Not bother trying to harass, concentrate on farming / last hitting
  Gank lanes as soon as possible

If you do have a choice then I would:

- Pick a a champ that will out farm her
- Pick a AD ranged champ (spell shield
  not so effective now!)
- Pick a tanky champ to mid vs her, i.e. Vlad / Galio, she isn't particulary dangerous on her own and its an easy lane for a tanky champ

Comment: Definitely a good choice. Part of becoming good at league is accepting when you are incapable of winning a fight. Your team should be balanced enough that an ally can take your place in mid.

Comment: I don't think Morganna farms better than Akali. Tainted Soil quickly becomes prohibitively expensive mana-wise if you level it first, and at level 1 it doesn't deal a massive amount of damage to easily farm minions. Akali doesn't have the same resource limitation. Furthermore, Akali has the same Spell Vamp as Morganna - perhaps even more so since Akali's Q is on such a short cooldown compared to Morganna's.

Answer (score 5):

Morgana will be a tough matchup for Akali, as Morgana's Black Shield and Soul Shackles do extremely well against Akali's magic damage and lack of an escape respectively.

What are your summoner spells? Cleanse can remove the stun, and flash can get you out of range when she pops her ult.

Akali's primary advantage is her use of energy. Try and drain Morgana's mana dry by goading her (and dodging, hopefully!) her skill shot and tormented soil.

Morganna's skillshot is very easy to land if you are in melee range with her, so rely on your Q to harass, simply farming minions until you see an opening.

Depending on your reaction times, it is quite possible to dodge Morgana's skillshot by Shadow Dancing *over* it -- another weakness of Morgana's is her cooldowns; but if you push as soon as she uses her Q, you've got at least 10 seconds where you don't have to worry about being rooted.

Unfortunately, there's no real counter to black shield other than to wait it out.

Comment: I am using Exchaust and Ignite, which garants me an early kill and probaly a good summoner spell choice agaist champs which can heal theirselve like warwick. But your idea is good. thank you

Answer (score 3):

As Akali you are a queen of both burst and sustained damage, having abilities on short cooldowns with no mana pool to worry about. Morgana is not a counter for you and you should be able to defeat her if you play to your abilities and against hers.

First, Morgana's damage is easy to avoid. Her snare is slow moving and easy to dodge, especially if you are around your minions, and her tormented soil is a very small AoE that you can step around. Even without boots you shouldn't be taking much damage from Morgana unless you are engaging.

If you are taking damage, do not forget that you yourself have spell vamp! Morgana has 15% early game while you have 10% from your passive **if you take an item giving you 10 attack damage**. You should really start with a Doran's Blade as Akali, which is a combined 10% spell vamp and 3% lifesteal. Even better, [select runes that give you spell vamp without having to buy items](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/akali-the-epitome-of-an-assassin-80578), then start with boots in order to dodge Morgana's skillshot. Morgana's abilities have 10 second cooldowns each, and yours are only 7 seconds decreasing per level, meaning you have more opportunities to vamp. The only edge Morgana has on you is that Tormented Soil has a large life return when used on groups of stationary minions; make sure you get a similar return (although it is much less) from Crescent Slash.

Don't get zoned! Morgana can't do much to you if you are in a minion wave except auto-attack. This will get your minions attacking her, and you can follow up with them for more damage. If you let Morgana push you out of your minion wave you'll have a hard time getting back unless you have your ult up.

Because Morgana's abilities have a large cooldown, take action when she uses one. In particular, watch for her using Dark Binding and Black Shield. If she has either down it is your opportunity to get in there. When Dark Binding is the only spell down Morgana's Black Shield *does not* make her immune to damage; it breaks after enough damage and your burst should be able to break it. Keep in mind that your abilities reset auto attacks, so alternate abilities and auto attacks to maximize damage while her shield is up. If her shield is down but Dark Binding is up, you might have trouble engaging if the Morgana is exceptional with it. Try to bait it out of her if possible.

Keep in mind that it's not always about killing your opponent. If the Morgana you are against saves her Dark Binding and Black Shield and is always using them at the right time, give up trying to kill her and focus on farming. Akali is amazing at farming, being able to reset auto-attacks and having two great damage spells. You may not outfarm Morgana given how awesome Tormented Soil is, but you will come close. Don't forget that you can return that pressure with lots of auto-attacks and using your abilities on minions - if you really feel like you cannot kill her you should always push back on her minion wave as hard as she pushes yours. If the Morgana pushes too hard signal to teammates (especially your jungler) and she will be easy to gank.

In most cases you can at least hold mid as Akali against Morgana. Both of you have good late game potential as well, so don't give up. If a teammate could do a better job than you in mid then let them do it. If you have to be mid just focus on farming, try your best, and don't get psyched out. You will get better and better as Akali and Morgana will only mid in less than 5% of the games you play anyways, she's not a typical mid nowadays in League of Legends.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to try and do would be to trick Morgana into shielding at the wrong time. 
Akali's Q (Mark of the Assassin) initial hit would be blocked my Morgana's Black Shield but the mark would stay on Morgana and just wait until the shield is gone and get the hit on Morgana consuming the mark and doing decent damage. Since Akali runs on energy you can do this until you have harassed enough and can get the kill, which would be easy with Exhaust and Ignite. Also, using Akali's shroud at a good time would allow for Morgana to waste her Tormented Soil, most Morgana will put their soil right where the shroud is and hope for some damage.

Depending on how the Morgana plays you could harass her and even zone her out if possible.

Comment: Morgana is much more likely to out-harass Akali. Akali has to auto attack with the mark on Morgana to deal any significant damage. A good Morgana will save the shield until you are in auto attack range. Morgana has spell vamp as a passive, making her laning presence much better (a good Akali will have to go b long before a good Morgana)

Comment: Well if the Morgana is saving her shield to block the consumption of the mark then the initial hit will deal damage. And if the Morgana is using her abilities just to get health back then in between she is open for some harassing. Also, Akali has her passive which is also spell vamp, percentage isn't as high but there is hardly and cooldown between her attacks.

Comment: This is good advice - Morgana's can't seem to resist putting their pool into a small area where they think you are, without realizing that Akali can safely stand on the edge of her shroud without taking damage from a pool in the middle. Also worth noting Akali gets more MR in shroud, so it does less damage anyways.